# Datatables.net json data load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to load the below json data into Datatables, but I'm facing error. My web browser(chrome) successfully downloads the data, but it does not represent the data. The table shows only the name of columns but nothing. Can someone please help me?

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Feature_ID": "4",
    "Clean_Feature_Name": "Abalos Colles",
    "Feature_Type": "Collis, colles",
    "Feature_Type_Code": "CO",
    "title": "['Arecibo radar imagery of Mars: II. Chryse-Xanthe, polar caps, and other regions']",
    "author": "['Harmon, John K.', 'Nolan, Michael C.']",
    "year": 2017,
    "bibcode": "2017Icar..281..162H",
    "pub": "Icarus"
  }
 }
]
}
```

And below is my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable( {
  "ajax" : {
    "url" : "http://212.201.46.76/data_final/sample_paper.json",
  },
  "columns" : [
    { "features" : "properties.Feature_Id" },
    { "features" : "properties.Clean_Feature_Name" },
    { "features" : "properties.Feature_Type" },
    { "features" : "properties.Feature_Type_Code" },
    { "features" : "properties.title" },
    { "features" : "properties.author" },
    { "features" : "properties.year" },
    { "features" : "properties.bibcode" },
    { "features" : "properties.pub" },
  ]
  } );
 } );
```

My HTML code

```
    <body>
  <button id="reload">Reload</button>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
        <th>Feature_ID</th>
        <th>Clean_Feature_Name</th>
        <th>Feature_Type</th>
        <th>Feature_Type_Code</th>
        <th>Bibcode</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Pub</th>                    
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
        <th>Feature_ID</th>
        <th>Clean_Feature_Name</th>
        <th>Feature_Type</th>
        <th>Feature_Type_Code</th>
        <th>Bibcode</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Pub</th>                    
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying your `columns` array wrong.

The `columns` array is where you specify a number of options in your table, on a per-column basis. There is no `features` option available; presumably that's why you're not seeing a table. Available values are [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/).

Now, you should be able to simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax" : {
      "url" : "http://212.201.46.76/data_final/sample_paper.json",
    }
  });
});
```

as in [this example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) (which you probably used to get started), removing your `columns` definition entirely. You've already specified the columns using HTML. If you need different options from the example, you need to learn to use `columns` correctly.

For more information on this, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943490).

Comment: thanks, helped me to get a hint though it was not exactly correct

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution. 
This is how you do when the json file has different format with examples.

"dataSrc" <-- follow your json format

{ "data" : "properties.title"} <-- "data" is always "data' it's a fixed key. you should not change it whatever "dataSrc" is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "ajax" : {
      "url": "http://212.201.46.76/data_final/sample_paper.json",
      "dataSrc": "features"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data" : "properties.title" },
        { "data" : "properties.author" },
        { "data" : "properties.year" },
        { "data" : "properties.bibcode" },
        { "data" : "properties.pub" }
    ] 
  });
```

Comment: "JSON file has different format from examples." Must have been a secret. At least, you didn't mention that in your question. :) Anyway, I'm glad my answer gave you a hint, and thanks for posting your solution. Yes, if the data you are looking for is nested in a "features" node, you'll have to specify "dataSrc" as you have done it here.