# Datatables.net no load JSON - SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, json, datatables, signalr

I want to load the following JSON object into Datatables.net but it does not work. I tried to find a solution like this: [Datatables.net json data load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967493/datatables-net-json-data-load), but without success.

I use SignalR to pass the JSON from the server-side to the client, and it runs because I can receive the JSON but I can't load it into a Datatable.

Please, could someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

**C# code:**

```cs
cmm_dbEntities db = new cmm_dbEntities();

var result = from a in db.TAB_PN
join b in db.TAB_APPL on a.idapplicability equals b.idapplicability
join c in db.TAB_ISSUE on a.idissue equals c.idissue
select new
{
    a.pn,
    a.title,
    b.appl_desc,
    c.issue,
    c.issue_date,
    c.rev,
    c.rev_date,
    a.equipment,
    a.formattype
};

var obj = new { data = result };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

return json;
```

**Here is my JSON:**

```
{
    "data": [{
        "pn": "346B0300A3300.801",
        "title": "Test Bench Replenish Unit, Engine Oil - Operation and Maintenance Manual with Illustrated Parts Breakdown",
        "appl_desc": "DESCRIZIONE 005",
        "issue": "ISSUE-003",
        "issue_date": "2015-03-01T00:00:00",
        "rev": "0003",
        "rev_date": "AAAAAAAAB9M=",
        "equipment": "Test Bench, Replenish Unit, Engine Oil",
        "formattype": "XML"
    }, {
        "pn": "346B0300A3300.805",
        "title": "Test Bench Replenish Unit, Engine Oil - Operation and Maintenance Manual with Illustrated Parts Breakdown",
        "appl_desc": "DESCRIZIONE 015",
        "issue": "ISSUE-004",
        "issue_date": "2015-04-01T00:00:00",
        "rev": "004",
        "rev_date": "AAAAAAAAB9Q=",
        "equipment": "Test Bench, Replenish Unit, Engine Oil",
        "formattype": "XML"
    }, {
        "pn": "415808",
        "title": "Operating and Maintenance Manual for Ni-Cd Aircraft batteries",
        "appl_desc": "DESCRIZIONE 015",
        "issue": "ISSUE-001",
        "issue_date": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
        "rev": "0001",
        "rev_date": "AAAAAAAAB9E=",
        "equipment": "Battery",
        "formattype": "XML"
    }, {
        "pn": "415818",
        "title": "Operating and Maintenance Manual for Ni-Cd Aircraft batteries",
        "appl_desc": "DESCRIZIONE 009",
        "issue": "ISSUE-002",
        "issue_date": "2015-02-01T00:00:00",
        "rev": "0002",
        "rev_date": "AAAAAAAAB9I=",
        "equipment": "Battery",
        "formattype": "XML"
    }]
}
```

**Here is my js:**

```js
hub.client.inizializzaFiltri = function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    $('#PNTable').DataTable({
        dataSrc: "objects",
        columns: [
            { data: null, defaultContent: '' },
            { data: 'pn' },
            { data: 'title' },
            { data: 'appl_desc' },
            { data: 'issue' },
            { data: 'issue_date' },
            { data: 'rev' },
            { data: 'rev_date' },
            { data: 'equipment' },
            { data: 'formattype' }],
        order: [[1, "asc"]],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets: 0
            },
        ],
        retrieve: true,
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        }
    });
}
```

**My HTML code:**

```
<table id="PNTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>pn</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>appl_desc</th>
            <th>issue</th>
            <th>issue_date</th>
            <th>rev</th>
            <th>rev_date</th>
            <th>equipment</th>
            <th>formattype</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>pn</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>appl_desc</th>
            <th>issue</th>
            <th>issue_date</th>
            <th>rev</th>
            <th>rev_date</th>
            <th>equipment</th>
            <th>formattype</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: In `console.log(data)`, is `data` is the JSON?

Comment: Do not serialize your `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);`. This will serialize your list twice and hence your DataTable is not getting initialized. Just do a `return Json(obj,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Comment: Thanks @rahulsharma for the answer... For use Json(obj,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) i have to added :Controller to my class. Anyway, now i receive a object but still not working. Thanks for looking into it

Comment: @rahulsharma i use SignalR for calling my hub.client.inizializzaFiltri method.

Comment: @darktemplar Since you are using webforms, the problem that I can understand is that you are not telling your `DataTable` where to get the data from. In your ajax, try specifying the url and dataSrc as: `"url": "data.json",  "dataSrc": "data"`. You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531438/jquery-datatables-server-side-processing-using-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again #naveen #ehsanmhdi and #rahsharm77 for your suggestions. 
I solved in this way...

C# code:

```
    ...
    var obj = new { data = result };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    return json;
```

JS code:

```
hub.client.inizializzaFiltri = function (data) {

    var jsn = JSON.parse(data);

    $('#PNTable').DataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "dataSrc": "",
    "data": jsn.data,
    "dataSrc": jsn.data,
     responsive: true,
     columns: [
        { "data": null, defaultContent: '' },
        { "data": 'pn' },
        { "data": 'title' },        
         ...
```

I have to Deserialize che JSON using JSON.parse(data) before to put it in the DataTable.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I did not see you setting the property `data`. Please assign `data: data` when you initialize the table.

```
hub.client.inizializzaFiltri = function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    $('#PNTable').DataTable({
        data: data //you are missing this
        dataSrc: "objects",
        columns: [
            { data: null, defaultContent: '' },
            { data: 'pn' },
            { data: 'title' },
            { data: 'appl_desc' },
            { data: 'issue' },
            { data: 'issue_date' },
            { data: 'rev' },
            { data: 'rev_date' },
            { data: 'equipment' },
            { data: 'formattype' }],
        order: [[1, "asc"]],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets: 0
            },
        ],
        retrieve: true,
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        }
    });
}
```